# Visual Studio 2010 git source control provider

Tags: visual-studio-2010, git

The git source control provider does not work Visual Studio 2010. I have installed it but I cannot see any icon in solution explorer, nor any "git" menu item. How can I fix it?

Comment: Installed it. It is there, but I cannot see any icon in solution explorer or any menu item "git"

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Go to Tools, Options, Source Control and select GIT

Comment: Someone should put this into howtos of git-extension

Comment: Yea that really wasn't obvious!

Comment: @ing0 Perhaps what's confusing is the fact that the GIT option won't show up only after Visual Studio is restarted. +1

Answer (score 2):

The git source control provider should work just fine in Visual Studio 2010.  Are you using the version from the extension manager?

- Tools -> Extension Manager
- Click Online Gallery
- Type in "git" into the search box

The first one that pops up should be "Git Source Control Provider".  Click download and it will install.

Comment: +1 for Git Source Control Provider. It really works well for me.

Comment: This didn't work for me (coulnd't find "Online gallery" anywhere in the extension manager). I had to download and install the .vsix file from the website, then select Git Source Control Provider from Tools-> Options -> Source Control.